# Неизвестные строки после...

Tags: php

Есть скрипт:

```
$x = "Пост №";
if ($forum[name] == $x) {
echo "Пост есть";
} else {
echo "Такого поста нету";
}
```

То есть вывожу все строки из базы, но у них после № есть ещё цифра, и надо, чтобы в запросе он не засчитывал то, что находиться после №.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x = 'Пост №';
if (stripos($forum['name'], $x) !== false) {
    echo 'Пост есть';
} else {
    echo 'Такого поста нету';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что?...

```
sprintf('select `body`,`title`,`id` from posts where `id`=%d',$forum[name]);
```

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: Приведите полностью кусок скрипта, относящийся к задаче